# How to convert AMR sound stream to PCM uncompressed stream in .NET

Tags: c#, audio, speech-recognition, pcm, amr

I need to convert an AMR (*Adaptive Multi-Rate*) audio file recorded in a phone (as a Stream object) to a PCM uncompressed wav audio Stream so it can be processed afterwards for speech recognition. The Speech Recognition doesn't like the AMR format. This is going to be a server application using the *Microsoft Speech Platform*. I am not sure about using the ffdshow or similar libraries in a .

Right now I am researching NAudio and DirectShowNet to see if they can help me accomplish this but was hoping someone can point in the right direction.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but perhaps these libraries are hard to find because of the license costs to develop AMR solutions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec#Licensing_and_patent_issues

Comment: Yeah. Most the the available ones are like that. I did find opencore-amr http://opencore-amr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Michael, thank you for the wiki link. I didn't know about these legal  issues. Luckily the decoding part is not an issue which is basically what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching for a solution for this, I am going to use **ffmpeg**. It provides the AMR-NB (NB=Narrow Band) decoder. There are a lot of c# wrappers for *ffmpeg* around; most of them abandoned efforts and one that is up to date but is not free. Just running *ffmpeg* with the basic parameters provides what I need, plus it is really fast.

I don't like the idea of calling an external process to do the conversion, plus I need to save the AMR stream as a file so it can be converted to a wav file but I believe I can make it work efficiently.